# Subquery in excel? How do I add the classification of one row to other rows with same ID?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My brain is on a ministrike, please advice.
So far Ive only been able to solve this with vlookup and pivot table. But I want a better solution than pivot.

I have two rows. 
A- unique ID. 
B- Purchase history of bags

Same client appears several times with different purchases.
If a client has a bag called X, I want to classify it as important for all purchases.
So where I have question marks I want "important" written.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it always “x” or are there other products that should be marked as important? If there are, is there any table to identify them? Does this apply to all clients?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz hello thanks , no I have 4 products as x. In reality they care called 16, “charm”, “c” and “T”.   It applies to all clients . So if you bought a bag called 16 and a watch you would be classified as important.

Comment: pivot solution: I created a pivot table filtered on x bag with id. I marked the Id as important if it was in the table next to the table . Then I did a vlookup on the client ids in the pivot from the original data set to match names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A2=$A$2:$A$4)*($B$2:$B$4="x"))>=1,"Important","Does not buy enough")
```

Now this is based on the assumption that the client only needs to purchase a least one x for the clients other purchases to flagged as important.

you could also probably achieve this with a straight COUNTIFS which would avoid the array calculations that SUMPRODUCT does.

UPDATE:

COUNTIFS solution

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$4,$A4,$B$2:$B$4,"x")>=1,"Important","Does not buy enough")
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much ! It is working but I’m most definitely going to figure out the countif version and brush up my vba. I have many lines and the sumproduct formula seems to murder and freeze everything.

Comment: @christinelly check the update and see if that helps you out.  Full column references are ok with COUNTIFS, but sumproduct will get bogged down with them.

Comment: Hi thousand thanks Ed!  But to verify it works I need to add a date condition as I only want to include data > February 3rd and I need to include the column L to be positive. I tried adding if(countifs(A:A;A4;B:B;”x”;L4:L4;>cell with date)>=1;”important”;”not enough”) to get the date and I tried + countif but I am stuck. I’ll let you know when I figure it out !

Comment: Use `= ISNUMBER(L4)` to test your date data.  if it comes back as true, its a date stored as a number which is what you need for date functions and comparisons to work.  If it comes back as false, it means its a date stored as text and needs to be converted to an excel date first before you can use it like a date.  Also you probably want `L:L` instead of `L4:L4`